# Easy way to remove chromakey from image Java

Tags: java, image, chromakey

Is there any easy way to remove the chromakey from the image by java?
I've tried to read about openCV and that's to hard to learn and use.

Comment: You question lacks detail, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution with would be to do the manipulation Pixel by Pixel.
For that to work you need an Image with an Alpha Channel. Pass `TYPE_INT_ARGB` to the Constructor of `BufferedImage` after width and height.

Then Copy in two nested `for` Loops each pixel to the new Image like this:

```java
BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(origImg.getWidth(), origImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Color background = new Color(0,0,0,0); //RGBA
for (int x = 0; x < origImg.getWidth(); x++) {          
   for (int y=0; y < origImg.getHeight(); y++) {
      Color newColor = new Color(origImg.getRGB(x, y) | 0xff000000, true);

      if(/*check for chromakey color*/)
        newImg.setRGB(x, y, background.getRGB())
      else
        newImg.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB());            
   }      
}
```

This assumes you dont have an alpha component in the original Image, because it will be overwritten by the `|0xff000000` with 255.